# Incrementing with async-await

Tags: vb.net, async-await

I was playing around with Async-Await in VS2012 and tried to increment a value while using multiple threads.

I know that I can use Interlocked.Increment to make the i += 1 threadsafe or use a synclock.

Which gives me this code.

```
    Imports System.Threading

Module Module1

    Private incre As New Incrementing

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Starting")
        Const numberofthreads As Integer = 20
        Dim ts(numberofthreads) As Task(Of Integer)
        For i = 0 To numberofthreads
            ts(i) = count()
        Next
        Task.WaitAll(ts)
        For i = 0 To numberofthreads
            Console.WriteLine(ts(i).Result)
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Async Function count() As Task(Of Integer)
        Await Task.Run(Sub()
                           For i = 1 To 1000
                               incre.Add()
                               Thread.Sleep(1)
                           Next
                       End Sub)
        Return incre.Read()
    End Function

    Public Class Incrementing
        Private i As Integer = 0

        Public Sub Add()
            Interlocked.Increment(i)
        End Sub

        Public Function Read() As Integer
            Return i
        End Function
    End Class
End Module
```

But it doesn't look very pretty, the Task.Run seems weird for one. Is there a better way of doing this?

It seems to me that the threaded way was less cluncky.

```
Imports System.Threading

Module Module1

    Private incre As New Incrementing

    Sub Main()
        For i = 0 To 20
            Dim t1 As New Thread(AddressOf count)
            t1.IsBackground = True
            t1.Start()
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Sub count()
        For i = 1 To 1000
            incre.Add()
            Thread.Sleep(1)
        Next
        Console.WriteLine(incre.Read())
    End Sub

    Public Class Incrementing
        Private i As Integer = 0

        Public Sub Add()
            Interlocked.Increment(i)
        End Sub

        Public Function Read() As Integer
            Return i
        End Function
    End Class
End Module
```